# A presence/activity set command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I was wondering if there could be a command I could write that allows me to set the bots presence and activity (ex. ~~set presence idle or ~~set activity watching "people typing ~~help") or something like that.

Unrelated question: How do I set commands to be used by me only?

I haven't found any example code for this, and i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`is_owner`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.is_owner) check to ensure that you are the only person who can invoke a command.

To change the presence or status of the bot, use the [`change_presence`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence) method:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, is_owner
from discord import Status, Activity, ActivityType

bot = Bot("~~")

def getEnum(enum):
    def getter(arg):
        return enum[arg]
    return getter

@bot.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@is_owner()
async def set(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You must provide a subcommand.")

@set.command()
async def presence(ctx, status: getEnum(Status)):
    await bot.change_presence(status=status)

@set.command(invoke_without_command=True)
async def activity(ctx, type: getEnum(ActivityType), *, description):
    await bot.change_presence(activity=Activity(type=type, name=description))

@set.error
async def set_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, BadArgument):
        await ctx.send(error.message)
        await ctx.send(error.args)

bot.run("token")
```

The above will fail silently if you try to provide an unrecognized name to `Status` or `ActivityType`, you could also try writing an [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) to provide some feedback.