# How do I make the "Watching" presence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How do I change the bot presence to say "Watching" instead of playing?

I've tried googling and googling but I cannot find ANYTHING for discord.py

```py
await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Discord Hack Week!'))
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56517170/6779307).  Basically, you have to create an `Activity` with the correct `ActivityType`, in this case `ActivityType.watching`

Comment: I apologize, I don't understand. I have to create a new event for `@set.command`? Is there a way to just do something like

`await bot.change_presence(ActivityType.watching(name='Discord Hack Week!'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `Activity` object with the `type` set to `ActivityType.watching`:

```
from discord import Activity, ActivityType

await bot.change_presence(activity=Activity(type=ActivityType.watching, name='Discord Hack Week!'))
```